# ddl-auto of Spring-JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

When I use  ddl-auto of Spring-JPA to create database tables, some of entities were created as tables, but some of tables not created

Spring-JPA entities(2):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlLOT.png)

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.open-in-view=false
```

tables of created by Spring-jpa
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJwBY.png)

---

there are tow entities, So I think there should be two tables created , but only one table named: tbl_app_block

1. I had added @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.entity.**"})
2. I generate entity by IDEA Database
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S7c8.png)

Entity1

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_app_auth", schema = "hoe_common", catalog = "")
public class TblAppAuthEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "app_id", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String appId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "app_secret", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String appSecret;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "app_name", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String appName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "app_token", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String appToken;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp createTime;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp updateTime;

    public String getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(String appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    public String getAppSecret() {
        return appSecret;
    }

    public void setAppSecret(String appSecret) {
        this.appSecret = appSecret;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public String getAppToken() {
        return appToken;
    }

    public void setAppToken(String appToken) {
        this.appToken = appToken;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Timestamp createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }

    public Timestamp getUpdateTime() {
        return updateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateTime(Timestamp updateTime) {
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TblAppAuthEntity that = (TblAppAuthEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(appId, that.appId) && Objects.equals(appSecret, that.appSecret) && Objects.equals(appName, that.appName) && Objects.equals(appToken, that.appToken) && Objects.equals(createTime, that.createTime) && Objects.equals(updateTime, that.updateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(appId, appSecret, appName, appToken, createTime, updateTime);
    }
}
```

Entity2

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_app_block", schema = "hoe_common", catalog = "")
public class TblAppBlockEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "block_id", nullable = false)
    private int blockId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "block_code", nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String blockCode;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "block_name", nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String blockName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "block_index", nullable = true)
    private Integer blockIndex;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "cross_num", nullable = true)
    private Integer crossNum;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp createTime;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = true)
    private Byte isDeleted;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sync_block_id", nullable = true)
    private Integer syncBlockId;

    public int getBlockId() {
        return blockId;
    }

    public void setBlockId(int blockId) {
        this.blockId = blockId;
    }

    public String getBlockCode() {
        return blockCode;
    }

    public void setBlockCode(String blockCode) {
        this.blockCode = blockCode;
    }

    public String getBlockName() {
        return blockName;
    }

    public void setBlockName(String blockName) {
        this.blockName = blockName;
    }

    public Integer getBlockIndex() {
        return blockIndex;
    }

    public void setBlockIndex(Integer blockIndex) {
        this.blockIndex = blockIndex;
    }

    public Integer getCrossNum() {
        return crossNum;
    }

    public void setCrossNum(Integer crossNum) {
        this.crossNum = crossNum;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Timestamp createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }

    public Byte getIsDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(Byte isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public Integer getSyncBlockId() {
        return syncBlockId;
    }

    public void setSyncBlockId(Integer syncBlockId) {
        this.syncBlockId = syncBlockId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TblAppBlockEntity that = (TblAppBlockEntity) o;
        return blockId == that.blockId && Objects.equals(blockCode, that.blockCode) && Objects.equals(blockName, that.blockName) && Objects.equals(blockIndex, that.blockIndex) && Objects.equals(crossNum, that.crossNum) && Objects.equals(createTime, that.createTime) && Objects.equals(isDeleted, that.isDeleted) && Objects.equals(syncBlockId, that.syncBlockId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(blockId, blockCode, blockName, blockIndex, crossNum, createTime, isDeleted, syncBlockId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post text, not images

Comment: Hello, the entity classes need to follow some requirement to be recognized by JPA as such. Please add the code of both classes as formatted text to the post.

Comment: @Mar-Z Hello, All of entities were generated by IntelliJ IDEA  Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a wrong type (String) of the ID field/column. As it should be generated by the database as IDENTITY it need to be Integer. Change like this:

```
@Column(name = "app_id", nullable = false)
private Integer appId;

public Integer getAppId() {
    return appId;
}

public void setAppId(Integer appId) {
    this.appId = appId;
}
```

You should also provide a non argument constructor in each of the entity class. It's not relevant for table creation but will be a problem later on while reading data.

Comment: thinks , that's useful !

Comment: Cool. Thanks for feedback. You can also mark the answer accordingly.